# Writing to a file duplicates the last entry in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list to a file in python but the last list item keeps duplicating in the file.

Here is what i have implemented:

```
with open('predicition_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in A:
        line = ("".join("%s"%a for a in item))
        f.write("%s\n" %line)
    print("Done")
```

Here is the content of the file:

```
SAB
BAB
BAB
```

Here is my expected output:

```
SAB
BAB
```

Comment: Have you verified the contents of `A`? That's almost certainly where the problem lies, but the code to generate `A` hasn't been posted and StackOverflow isn't a very good debugger.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that will cause anything to be duplicated. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `A` item because nothing is wrong

```
A = ['SAB','BAB']

with open('predicition_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in A:
        line = ("".join("%s"%a for a in item))
        f.write("%s\n" %line)
    print("Done")
```

output file

```
SAB
BAB
```